# How can I deal with rendering a selected template - getting a ,,Http request has no attribute'' meta error

Tags: python, django, httprequest

```
def thanks(request):
    template = select_template(['poll/a.html', 'poll/b.html'])
    template.render({'a': 'b'}, HttpRequest)
```

This is my code and it throws an error as above. I tried using return too. In documentaion it tells that it should be specifically HttpRequest, not request. Where is the problem?

Comment: Please post the full error message. Also the docs say it must be -an- HttpRequest, not that is must be HttpRequest. I usually use the render function to return from views so this method is not something I've used before.

Comment: what is the return class of variable template ?

Comment: Googling around I see examples like `return HttpResponse(t.render(context))` and (clearer to me at least) `return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))`

Comment: `select_template` returns a Template object

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a really handy way to render your templates.

Create a folder in your app and name it "templates":

```
your_app
   templates
      base.html
      imprint.html
   views.py
   models.py
   ...
```

In case you want to render the imprint.html as a return of your function thanks() in your view you can do it like:

views.py:

```
def thanks(request):
    #here you can write your code
    return render(request, "your_app/imprint.html",
```

Comment: `def thanks(request):
    return render(request,['poll/b.html', 'poll/a.html'], {'a': 'b'})`  - this seems to be the correct solution. Anyway, thanks for help. It turns out select_template is used to select a template from templates passed in a list.